# invalid 'in' in operand a

Tags: jquery, ajax

I send the request to server using jquery `$.ajax` and it returns JSON.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'moreMonth.ajax',
  data: { startIndex: id },
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(k, v) {
      alert(k + ':' + v); 
    });
  }
});
```

But I've got an error

> invalid 'in' in operand a

As far as I can understand - is it a problem with `success` block?

Log:

```
"[
  {"name":"Advanced Complexity Theory.rar","size":672398,"present":true,"display":false,"publisherId":1,"downloadDate":"Jun 9, 2014 11:05:28 AM","id":11},
  {"name":"Algorithms and Complexity, Internet Edition.rar","size":971299,"present":true,"display":false,"publisherId":1,"downloadDate":"Jun 9, 2014 11:05:28 AM","id":12}
]"
```

Comment: what is the format of data?

Comment: try to `console.log(data)` in the success callback and post here the result

Comment: @AnoopJoshi JSON. as a response I assume it's string

Comment: I think this question is valid. why down votes after detailing with log?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are trying to iterate over a string, that is causing this error

variable `data` is string, try converting that to an array.

Try using `$.parseJSON(data)`

```
    $.ajax({
               url: 'moreMonth.ajax',
               data: { startIndex: id },
               success: function(data) {
                   data = $.parseJSON(data);
                   $.each(data, function(k, v) {
                      alert(k + ':' + v); 
                   });
               }

});
```

Comment: `data = JSON.Parse(data);`

Answer (score 1):

Make the data as json object first, then parse it.

USe `jQuery.parseJSON(` for converting string to json object

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'moreMonth.ajax',
    data: {
        startIndex: id
    },
    success: function (data) {
        data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        $.each(data, function (k, v) {
            alert(k + ':' + v);
        });
    }
});
```